# How to print Excel using C# WPF without Office installed?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have used NPOI to generate the Excel file, but I can't find any way to print it.

1. I know Spire.xls can print, but it's for winform, not for WPF, which is not what I want.
2. I tried to convert Excel to .pdf, but to print a .pdf, you need to install extra software like Adobe.
3. I can't force my client to install Office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to convert the Excel file to HTML, then print the HTML using whichever web browser you prefer. HTML/CSS provides limited control over page breaks, but aside from that, it should be reasonably easy to convert any Excel cell into an appropriately-styled HTML table cell.

FWIW, I prefer EPPlus over NPOI for working with Excel files in C#.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.